# How can I compute a rolling window in Python for a multi asset matrix?

Tags: python, rolling-computation

I have 1610 observations for 3 assets and I want to compute a covariance matrix `Σ = σDσ` where `σ` is a diagonal matrix of 3x3 of the variances of my 3 assets, and `D` is the correlation matrix of my 3 assets. I wanted this matrix `Σ` for a rolling window of 60 observations so I can eventually feed this as the sigma in the value at risk formula to compute the value at risk.

The problem is I'm not sure how to program the rolling window, I only know how to program the default correlation matrix `D` with rolling window but I want to pre and post multiply it with the diagonal σ matrix. What I have done so far is:

```
for I in range (T):
     a = sigmabtc[‘gas’].iat[i]
     b = sigmaeth[‘gas’].iat[i]
     c = sigmaxlm[‘gas’].iat[i]
     X = (a,b,c)
     σ = np.diag(X)
     D = returns.corr 
     Σ = σ*D*σ
```

This approach doesn’t take the rolling window one by one for all observations, I tried to use the function `rolling(Σ)` however it doesn’t work.

I could only compute the matrix `D`:

```
returns.rolling(60).corr(pairwise=True)
```

Could anyone suggest a method to also feed the diagonal matrix `σ` before and after this correlation matrix also with rolling window?

Comment: The quotes in the assignments for `a`, `b`, and `c`, don't look quite right. Is that _exactly_ how they appear in your original source code?

Comment: No i just couldn’t find the right ones here on my keyboard , in my code they are symmetrical